# Date format by JavaScript to dd/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datepicker

I want to change date format to *"dd/MM/YYYY"* when i change it  gives me another wrong date. adddate() function set by default arrival date and departure 
date on load .changedDate() change departure date when i change arrival date .

```js
addDate();
function addDate() {
  date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = date.getDate();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  if (document.getElementById('startDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('startDate').value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('endDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('endDate').value = month + '/' + (day + 1) + '/' + year;
  }
}
function changedDate(){
  var arrivalDate = new Date(document.getElementById('startDate').value) ;
  var departureDate = new Date(document.getElementById('endDate').value) ;
  if(arrivalDate>=departureDate){
    var arrDate = new Date();
    arrDate.setDate(arrivalDate.getDate()+1);
    arrDate.setMonth(arrivalDate.getMonth()+1);
    arrDate.setFullYear(arrivalDate.getFullYear());
    document.getElementById('endDate').value = arrDate.getMonth() + '/' + arrDate.getDate() + '/' + arrDate.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkin" placeholder="checkin" onchange="changedDate()">
<input type="text" id="endDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkout" placeholder="checkout">
```

Comment: yes but i want date to be d/m/y

Comment: @Jaromanda X, there is a `.getMonth()+1` in his code that takes care of that

Comment: arrival  m/d/y departure  m/d+1/y this is my out put

Comment: @8odoros the problem  in change date i get 11/08/2016 12/08/2016  when i change arrival date nothing changed

Comment: @JaromandaX yes the problem is i want to change date format to dd/mm/yyyy from mm/dd/yyyy that is all i want

Comment: well swap month and day ... it's not rocket surgery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assigned month + date + year. Change it like below.

```js
addDate();

function addDate() {
  date = new Date();
  var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (month < 10)
    month = '0' + month;
  var day = date.getDate();
  if (day < 10)
    day = '0' + day;
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  if (document.getElementById('startDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('startDate').value = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('endDate').value == '') {
    document.getElementById('endDate').value = (day + 1) + '/' + month + '/' + year;
  }
}

function changedDate() {
  var startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value.split("/");
  var endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value.split("/");

  var arrivalDate = new Date(startDate[2], startDate[1] - 1, startDate[0]);
  var departureDate = new Date(endDate[2], endDate[1] - 1, endDate[0]);

  if (arrivalDate >= departureDate) {
    var arrDate = arrivalDate;
    arrDate.setDate(arrDate.getDate() + 1);

    var month = arrDate.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10)
      month = '0' + month;
    var day = arrDate.getDate();
    if (day < 10)
      day = '0' + day;
    var year = arrDate.getFullYear();

    document.getElementById('endDate').value = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="startDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkin" placeholder="checkin" onchange="changedDate()">
<input type="text" id="endDate" style="background-color:#5c677b;height:25px;" name="checkout" placeholder="checkout">
```

Comment: @hashim : What do you wanna do when `arrivalDate >= departureDate` ??

Comment: change departureDate  when the arrivaldate change add one day to departureDate

Answer (score 0):

There is a free library available called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) in which you can play with date formatting very easily.

```
moment().format('dd/MM/YYYY');
```